# C# object stored on disk (MemoryMappedFile?)

Tags: c#

I have a set of large objects (over 20GB) that I need to access quickly from an application.

So far I have read these files from disk, to RAM on application startup. This is an expensive task as the files are deserialized to an in-memory object. However, after the initial startup delay in loading these files, the objects can be accessed very quickly. Now however, the sizes of the files are now too large to store in RAM.

I am now having to read part of the files from disk, deserializing them to memory, then discarding the used memory, reading the next files, and so on in a loop. This is very expensive computationally due to the deserialization.

Is there a way where I can have an "in-memory" object that points to a memory space that is stored on disk? This would be slower to access than if it was resident in RAM, but the slower access to disk rather than RAM would still be faster than repeatedly deserializing the data I suspect.

Is there a way to do this?

The data btw is essentially a List of structs that need to be iterated over.

Comment: The code could certainly map the "on-disk" locations of objects itself and perform caching, as relevant/practical, but there is no support in .NET for this level of 'transparent' object management.. Perhaps some form of existing DB - relational or otherwise - might be able to help speeding up [non-sequential] access [and provide caching]?

Comment: What is the problem with the OS's builtin disk backed virtual memory? You just allocate as much memory as you like, and the OS should handle the rest.

Comment: As far as I know there is no performance benefit in using memory mapped files vs swap file (in fact the swap file is a special case of memory mapped files). As such you can just read the data and deserialize them to C# objects and let the operating system do the swapping to disk.

Comment: @TamasHegedus could you please elaborate?

Comment: So if my machine has 48GB RAM, and I am allocating 100GB, Windows should automatically move the additional memory to swap?

Comment: @Ibraheem As long as you have a large enough swap file.

Comment: "Allocating 100GB" - surely that's not a reasonable design for most tasks :} It may be beneficial to re-consider the problem space and data-access to operate within a small footprint.

Comment: Design requirement is speed of recursive calculations over the data set, using the hardware available. It's micro-optimising now.

Comment: @Ibraheem Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @suchoss no I wasn't I'm afraid. If I remember correctly I opted to benchmark different serializers and used the fastest one for the particular data. If you can partition the data then you could execute in parallel across machines and collect the result from each node. Which is also just using more RAM.

Answer (score 4):

If it is essentially a list of structs, then yes: you can use memory mapped files here. The most effective way to do this would be to create a single huge view over the data (let the OS worry about mapping it and paging it as needed), and obtain and store the unmanaged pointer to the root (you can get that from `MemoryMappedViewStream`, but IIRC there are more direct ways to get it).

Now; two things you *don't* want to do:

- constantly deal in unmanaged pointers
- constantly copy the data

But: you can use `ref T` and `Span<T>` as your friend; [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/) has facilities to hack between `void*` and `ref T`, and `Span<T>` *can take a `void*`*; this gives you two easy ways of working with `struct` data that is held in unmanaged memory.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in detail?

Comment: This sounds interesting, can you please provide further detail, a simple example?